# Xcode 7 does it support iOS 8.0 simulator?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode7, xcode6.4

I have a problem with Xcode 7. I can't install iOS 8.0 simulator. It is not an option for download. I can download alone iOS 8.1 to 9.0 simulator and I need to test the app in 8.0 version. How can I make this?

Also I installed Xcode 6.4 but I can't install iOS 8.0 Simulator. It is not available. My app run good in iOS 8.1, must it run good in iOS 8.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although Xcode 7 does support the iOS 8 deployment target, it does not ship with or support the iOS 8.0 Simulator.  If you want to make sure your app "runs good" on iOS 8.0, you should test with a real device running iOS 8.